# Migrating from oracle sql developer to postgres

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT DISTINCT((SELECT array_to_string(a, '') FROM regexp_matches(V_REC.WERS_ENTITY, '[^_]+', 'g') AS foo(a) LIMIT 1 OFFSET (LEVEL - 1))) VALUE
                        CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  LENGTH(V_REC.WERS_ENTITY) - LENGTH( replace(V_REC.WERS_ENTITY, '_' , '') ) + 1
```

I am getting error like this, can anyone help me. In oracle DUAL table is used.I tried using  postgres syntax and getting this error
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CONNECT"
LINE :                         CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  LENGTH(V_REC.WE...

Comment: i dont think dual tables are a thing in postgres, I dont recognize the 'connect' keyword. Maybe you need union

Comment: What does the code do? If you want to turn a comma separated list into rows use `string_to_table()` (or a combination of `string_to_array()` and `unnest()` if you are on an older Postgres version )

Comment: You will have to rewrite this proprietary SQL dialect to standard SQL. [Here](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/recursive-queries-postgresql/) is an article that contains some information how to do that.

Comment: Please see [Migrate your mindset](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/migrate-your-mindset/). While it mainly mentions SQL Server; but you could substitute any database name (for either) and everything would still apply. BTW `dual` does not exist in Postgres , nor does `connect by`.